# What method can be used to print variables as inject iterates through a range?

Tags: ruby, methods, inject, method-chaining

Using method chaining I would like to amend the following code so that on each iteration the variables mult and n are printed. What method can help accomplish this?

```
(1..3).inject {|mult, n| mult * n}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Enumerable#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) is what you need

```
(1..3).inject { |mult, n| (mult * n).tap { |next_mult| p [n, mult, next_mult] } }
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding his question, this doesn't *quite* do what he needs... for me this code outputs `mult * n` at each iteration, but I believe he wants to output both independently at each step (so, your answer outputs two numbers but he wants 4). I may be wrong, though...

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I missed that. Edited the post.

Comment: Nice. I guess you can use `tap` to execute whatever code you like in a 'method chaining' style. :)

Comment: Okay, that's pretty close to what I wanted to accomplish, but I want to see what inject is doing for every member of the range. The block that `tap` runs results in showing 2 steps that `inject` runs and the final result. Since it is operating upon a range of three I would imagine it should output three arrays, instead of just two. I might be, and probably am, missing something very obvious here.

Comment: You did not pass an argument to `#inject`, therefore it uses first element of your array as the first `mult`, so it has to run only two remaining iterations. You can call `inject(1)` instead of `inject` and see how it runs three times.

Comment: @mdunsmuir: Yes, that's precisely what it is there for, to "tap into" a method chain without changing the flow of return values. It's the [K Combinator](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus#Informal_description), basically.

Answer (score 1):

This looks simpler to me than the `tap` solution.  It may be a matter of taste.

```
(1..3).inject do |mult, n|
  puts "#{mult} #{n}"
  mult * n
end

1 2
2 3
=> 6
```

To answer bodhidarma's other question about the number of iterations, the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) say:

> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then uses the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
>> (1..3).inject {|mult, n| r =  mult * n; p "mult = #{mult}, n = #{n}, mult * n = #{r}"; r}
"mult = 1, n = 2, mult * n = 2"
"mult = 2, n = 3, mult * n = 6"
```